# wso2 - using value from a property to retrive sequence name

Tags: wso2, sequence, esb

I'm configuring a proxy-service and I have three sequences: s1,s2,s3

The value of 1,2,3 is stored in a local registry variable and it's get from the registry and stored in the property called 'myProp'

now, based on the value of this myProp I would like to call one of the three sequences.

I tried this:

```
               <sequence key="s{concat(get-property('myProp'))}"/>
```

but doesn't works.

This is the property code:

```
         <property name="myProp"
               expression="get-property('registry','conf:repository/myVersion2.xml')"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
```

and this is what I'm trying to do:

```
         <filter source="get-property('myProp')"
             regex=".*&gt;1&lt;.*"
             description="filter">
        <then>
           <log level="custom" separator=":">
              <property name="TestVersion" value="LOG_S1_TRUE"/>
              <property name="TestVersion" expression="get-property('myProp')"/>
           </log>
           <sequence key="s{concat(get-property('myProp'))}"/>
        </then>
        <else>
           <log level="custom" separator=":">
              <property name="TestVersion" value="LOG_S1_FALSE"/>
           </log>
        </else>
     </filter>
```

I get this error from the log:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-03 12:47:25,340] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator} -  Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='s{concat(get-property('myProp'))}'} cannot be found {org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator}
```

Thanks in advance to who know how to solve it.

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the keyvalue to a property first to test it, you will notice that it cannot work :) 
Try:
`<sequence key="{concat('s', get-property('myProp'))}"/>`